# Update boolean field in ItemAdding receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I want to update a SP boolean column on an ItemAdding event receiver. I want to set the "Hide physical URLs from search" column (PublishingIsFurlPage) to Yes.

My code look like this :

```
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
     EventFiringEnabled = false;

     properties.AfterProperties["PublishingIsFurlPage"] = "1";

     EventFiringEnabled = true;

     base.ItemAdding(properties);
  }
```

It does nothing event if I used "True", "TRUE", true instead of "1".

Anyone have an idea how to set this boolean column ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AfterProperties` is generally not the approach I go with, since it's often buggy/not behaving the way we expect (see for instance [Working with BeforeProperties and AfterProperties on SPItemEventReceiver](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122)).

First thing, why do you use `ItemAdding`? In your case, wouldn't `ItemAdded` -in an asynchronous ER- be more suited?

In an `ItemAdded`, I'd then have no problem to run this code:

```
base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
item["PublishingIsFurlPage"] = true;
item.SystemUpdate();
base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```

If you want to continue on with `ItemAdding`, here are two things to check:

1. For a Yes/No field, assign the boolean `true`, not the string `"1"`, `"True"` or anything else.
2. Be sure you use the *internal* name of the field.

Comment: Thanks. I already try your solution in ItemAdded but I've always got the The file Pages/sss.aspx has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system. Very frustrating. Any idea ? When I do not trace the ItemAdded, I don't have this erreur but the boolean is not even set.

Comment: There may be another ER linked to your list. This is a publishing page in the Pages doc lib? Or the page may be created, your ER triggers, but at the same time the page is checked-out for editing... For a test, you can try to get a new fresh SPListItem, not from properties.ListItem, but with SPListItem item = properties.List.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId).

Comment: I try  SPListItem item = properties.List.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId) and I got the same error. Yes, the file is checked out and it's a publishing page from the page doc lib.

Comment: Then, the simplest/best/fastest/etc. option may be to have that ER on the checked-in event. Is this an option?

Comment: It's not a good option for what we do. I have no solution :(

Comment: Finally I have an ER on the checked-in event. Not the best solution but it works and we can live with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution :

```
using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
                  {
                     bool oldUnsafeUpdates = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                     SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Pages");

                     SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

                     item["PublishingIsFurlPage"] = true;
                     item.SystemUpdate(false);

                     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                  }
```

> **Edit** 
>   Work when adding one document. The second one give me the error The file Pages/z.aspx has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system

Damn